# pgfplot addplot3 giving a weird undesired line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to use PGFplots to draw a surface of a wave, z = sin(x + y).
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\let\oldvec\vec
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{comment}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={wave}{rgb255(0cm)=(214,196,194); rgb255(1cm)=(183,166,158)}}

\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sen}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$t$,
    small,
    colormap/wave
]

% Onda
\addplot3[
    surf,shader=interp,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    domain y=0:3*pi,
    samples=50,
    samples y=50,
] 
    (x , y , {sin((x - y)*360/pi)});

% Senoide do tempo
\addplot3[
    thick,black,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    domain y=0:3*pi,
    samples=10,
    samples y=50,
] 
    (2*pi , y , {sin(-y*360/pi)});

% Senoide do comprimento
\addplot3[
    thick,blue,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    domain y=0:3*pi,
    samples=50,
    samples y=10,
] 
    (x , 0 , {sin(x*360/pi)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have the wave surface and also two sine waves to acompany the borders, in which I'll make annotations later on.

The MWE results in:
[image: MWE result]

And I have this weird blue line on my z=0, all along my x axis. I have no idea what is causing it. Anyone has a clue? I'm looking at this for the better part of an hour or so and it's driving me crazy.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions on how to make a "sharper" surface, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome! In the last plot, replace `samples y=10,` by `samples y=0,`.

Comment: Well that worked!

It's funny that I had that line removed, and it didn't work. I had to force a 0 there.

Comment: Sure, this is because the default/initial value is not 0. If you remove the line, you get the default value of `25` (I believe). If you could explain a bit more what "sharper" surface means, one could try to solve this problem, too.

Comment: Actually I can't explain precisely. Last night I kept fidgeting with the code and ended up getting the plot pretty much as I wanted it. I'll post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Schrödinger's cat said in a comment, the problem was with `samples y =10`, which had to change to 0.

I ended up changing a lot of the plot, and here is the final result:

```latex
    % Adaptado de (BAUER, WESTFALL, DIAS, 2013, p.86, Figura 3.8)
    % Adaptado de (BAUER, WESTFALL, 2014, p.466, Figure 15.8)
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \let\oldvec\vec
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \pgfplotsset{colormap={wave}{rgb255=(145,85,61) rgb255=(229,200,168) rgb255=(255,240,225) rgb255=(229,200,168) rgb255=(145,85,61)}}

    \definecolor{length}{rgb}{0 , 0.5 , 0}
    \definecolor{time}{rgb}{0 , 0 , 1}

    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={-45}{30},
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$t$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        zlabel style={rotate=-90},
        zmin=-1,
        zmax=1,
        ticks=none,
        grid=none,
        colormap name=wave
    ]

    % Senoide do comprimento
    \addplot3[
        very thick,black,
        domain=0:720,
        domain y=0:1080,
        samples=70,
        samples y=0,
    ] 
        (x , 1080 , {sin(-x)});

    % Senoide do tempo
    \addplot3[
        very thick,black,
        domain=0:720,
        domain y=0:1080,
        samples=70,
    ] 
        (720 , y , {sin(y)});

    % Onda
    \addplot3[
        surf,shader=interp,
        domain=0:720,
        domain y=0:1080,
        samples=70,
    ] 
        (x , y , {sin(y - x)});

    % Senoide do tempo
    \addplot3[
        very thick,time,
        domain=0:720,
        domain y=0:1080,
        samples=70,
    ] 
        (0 , y , {sin(y)});

    % Senoide do comprimento
    \addplot3[
        very thick,length,
        domain=0:720,
        domain y=0:1080,
        samples=70,
        samples y=0,
    ] 
        (x , 0 , {sin(-x)});

    % Indicação do período da onda
    \draw[time,dashed] ( 0 , 90 , -1 ) -- (0 , 90 , 1);
    \draw[time,dashed] ( 0 , 450 , -1 ) -- (0 , 450 , 1);
    \draw[time, <->] ( 0 , 90 , 0 ) -- (0 , 450 , 0);
    \draw (0 , 270 , 0) node[above]{\color{time}$\mathbf{T}$};

    % Indicação do comprimento da onda
    \draw[length,dashed] ( 270 , 0 , -1 ) -- ( 270 , 0 , 1);
    \draw[length,dashed] ( 630 , 0 , -1 ) -- ( 630 , 0 , 1);
    \draw[length, <->] ( 270 , 0 , 0 ) -- (630 , 0 , 0);
    \draw (450 , 0 , 0) node[above]{\color{length}$\pmb{\lambda}$};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

And here is the picture:
[image]

Regarding the sharpness of the surface, maybe adding a black countour to the outer planes. I did this by adding a new plot, very thick and black to those planes, but I'm pretty sure my code isn't the most elegant or well refined out there.